# square icon with rounded corners in an Android app

Tags: android, kotlin, android-shapedrawable

The following kotlin code is used to display a square icon in an Android app.
But I would also like to set rounded corners to it; and this is where things go wrong.
Any tip would be welcome as what to do to get the rounded corners working.

```
    val apIcnID = resources.getIdentifier("appIcon","id",packageName)
    val apIcnCompo = findViewById<ImageView>(apIcnID)

    val borderSz = 9F; val cornerRad = 16F
    val shape = ShapeDrawable(
        RoundRectShape(
            floatArrayOf(cornerRad, cornerRad, cornerRad, cornerRad,
                cornerRad, cornerRad, cornerRad, cornerRad),
            RectF(borderSz, borderSz, borderSz, borderSz),
            floatArrayOf(cornerRad, cornerRad, cornerRad, cornerRad,
                cornerRad, cornerRad, cornerRad, cornerRad)
        )
    )

    //apIcnCompo.clipToOutline = true // Uncommenting this line hides the whole image.
    apIcnCompo.background = shape
    apIcnCompo.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher_myapp)
    // I see the square-icon image, but with no single rounded corner ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace cornerRadius with your desired corner radius.

```
val apIcnID = resources.getIdentifier("appIcon","id",packageName)
val apIcnCompo = findViewById<ImageView>(apIcnID)
    
val borderSz = 9F; val cornerRad = 16F
// similarCornerRadius
val roundCorners = FloatArray(8) { cornerRadius }        


val shape  = ShapeDrawable().apply {
        shape = RoundRectShape(roundCorners, null, null)
        paint.color = Color.RED
    }
apIcnCompo.background = shape
apIcnCompo.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher_myapp)
apIcnCompo.clipToOutline = true // Added by @Michel.
```

OR

```
val apIcnID = resources.getIdentifier("appIcon","id",packageName)
val apIcnCompo = findViewById<ImageView>(apIcnID)
    
val borderSz = 9F; val cornerRad = 16F
// similarCornerRadius
val roundCorners = FloatArray(8) { cornerRadius }        

apIcnCompo.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher_myapp)

val gd = GradientDrawable();
//gd.Color(Color.RED); // Edited by @Michel.
//gd.CornerRadius(10); // Edited by @Michel.
//gd.Stroke(2, Color.WHITE); // Edited by @Michel. (3 next lines)
gd.setColor(Color.RED)
gd.cornerRadius = 10F
gd.setStroke(2,Color.WHITE)

apIcnCompo.setBackground(gd);
apIcnCompo.clipToOutline = true // Added by @Michel.
```

Comment: Thank you, but I tried both of you suggestions and none of them worked. In the second one you do not use roundCorners; is this normal?

Comment: Though it first didn't work, trying further I made both of your solutions work and accepted you answer. Please take a look at your answer. I made some change to it to reflect what I had to do to make it work for me. Some of the things I had to change may be due to the version of Android and Android Studio I am using. Anyway I am interested to read you comments if you have some.

Comment: @Mitchel Thank you for the edit you have done. It was great to contirbute something here.